# How to fix emulator not working because of extension?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am new to coding and visual studio code. My problem is after I launch the android emulator and try to change the color but the emulator did not work. So after u change the code did it change by itself or u have to click some run button to make the emulator work. I ask it on Github and they said it is caused by the extension but how do you fix it...

Comment: Hi @lim, welcome to SO! Please provide more details to your question so users can better reproduce, and please consider posting your issue at the right GitHub repo, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect your problem is being caused by a vscode extension, you can try running an extension bisect ("Help: Start Extension Bisect" in the `Ctrl+Shift+P` menu). This will restart vscode several times, each time you should run the emulator and determine if the issue is still present. After this process is finished, it should let you know what extension causes the issue, or let you know that your issue isn't caused by a vscode extension.